# How to use $toObjectId for array of ids during $addFields stage after performing $map?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

How can I convert ids that are string into object ids?

### **$addFields**

```
{
  otherSchemasIds: {
    ids: {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$carEquipments",
        "as": "carEquipment",
        "in": "$$carEquipment._panelId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

For the next stage I have the needed ids for $lookup.
But the things is that those ids are strings and in other schema they would be object ids.
And "6093de34b34bac74c4d5fcf8" is not equal to ObjectId("6093de34b34bac74c4d5fcf8"); thus I cannot match the ids from another schema.

How can I convert _panelId to be object id withing $addFields stage?

Comment: you just simply need to convert `in: { _panelId: { $toObjectId: "$$carEquipment._panelId } }`,  for clear example can you post some sample document..

Comment: Thank you, it worked!
I added it like that:
```
in: {  $toObjectId: "$$carEquipment._panelId } 
```